# Can not install Polymer CLI 3

Tags: polymer

I am trying to upgrade to Polymer 3 from Polymer 2. My environment follows:

- Debian Stretch
- npm version 6.1.0

command run with root account: `npm install -g polymer-cli`

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

```
/usr/bin/polymer -> /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/bin/polymer.js

> wd@1.6.2 install /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd
> node scripts/build-browser-scripts

/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
                    throw err0;
                    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/build'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:902:18)
    at sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/scripts/build-browser-scripts.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be caused by npm issue [#17346](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17346#issuecomment-320238079).

The current workaround is to call `npm install -g polymer-cli` with the `--unsafe-perm` flag until a new fix is released.